# How to use MasterCard/Visa Payment system in an iOS App instead of AppStore one for IAP (In-App-Purchase)?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment, subscription, mastercard

I have an App in Appstore that is Free & provides different modules that will be accessible to people who made an Annual Subscription !

**MY QUESTION**

Is it possible to use my own Payment system like in "Airline Companies Apps" i.e : American Airlines, Ryanair etc...? Those apps have a MasterCard/Visa System !

Comment: Only if you are selling physical goods or a service can you leverage someone's credit card

Comment: Like uber, airbnb and airlines:)

Comment: If you have physical goods, you can allow external payment systems. However, if they aren't physical goods, your app will be rejected for using external payment methods.

Comment: @Schemetrical Thanks for the answer ! I actually provide an Access to a Professional database with different digital modules through a Login Form...i have also a website and Android version !

Comment: @DanielGalasko Thanks for the Answer ! The point is that my service is Digital :P

Comment: If its a digital product thats unlocked through the app then you have to use an IAP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider familiarizing yourself with the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Specifically section 11 which outlines Purchasing and Currency in the iOS world. Typically you can't use the users credit card for any digital products that can be used in your App. This is why Kindle, for instance, only let you add books to your wishlist.

Apps like Airbnb and Uber offer physical services which allow them to use the users card.

In Apple's words

> **11.2** Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to
>   purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
>   rejected

And if you think you can be clever and direct the user from your App to your site to make the payment, think again

> **11.3** Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes
>   to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Comment: Thanks ! I will Find Another Way For Example subscribing users via the Website and then Via Parse Give them the possibility to access different modules ! What do you think ?

Comment: As long as you don't direct them from the app to your site you can do that:)

Comment: For Exemple: in my iOs App I give a link to the website that redirect my app to Safari ! Then Via The website the user do the subscription and if the subscription is Done...a Boolean will be created in my Parse.com Server...i.e: YES if the subscription has been done & No for the contraire. And in my app i will call At the login the USER Class (Where the boolean is") and it will give access to the user the different modules !

Comment: Please read my comment above, you cannot direct them from the app to your website to make a purchase. section 11.3 Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Comment: I liked your previous Comment ! i was writing you my comment when you posted yours :P I understand everything :D Thanks !